# focus does not move with voiceover in scrollable area

Tags: html, accessibility

I have one form which has scrollbar associated with it . page reads properly element by element but focus does not move with voiceover.

I am testing this html form in iphone 5 with ios 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus only moves to elements that are tab focusable. These are elements like links, buttons and input fields or elements that have an explicit tabindex attribute greater than or equal to 0. Voiceover and other screen readers will read out intervening text, but leave the focus on the most recently visited focusable element until the next focusable element is encountered, at which point the focus will jump to that element as it gets read out. This is the way it should work and there is nothing "wrong" with this behavior.

Comment: Select elements are not focusable? Focus is not going to select elements or checkboxes.

Comment: OK, this looks like a bug on iOS for select elements specifically. It works differently from OS X take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/evbuuz63/1/embedded/result/

Comment: It works fine if select element comes first place but if it is not visible in viewport and if we try to scroll then it is not focusable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981995/accessibility-voicerover-does-not-move-focus-to-select-element

Comment: any solution for above scenario

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple

Comment: can u please share link for the same?

Comment: to file bugs with Apple email accessibility@apple.com, no bug repo that I know of